# Who exactly was in the Schuman group (that left the EPP in 2000 during "Haider affair") and what (other) group did they form in 2004?

Tags: european-parliament

I've [read](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/01402380500085905) that:

> On 13 April 2000, for instance, several
>   representatives of the EPP-ED (including some Belgian, Dutch and Italian
>   Christian democrats as well as the French UDF) created a centre-right
>   group inside the EPP-ED, the ‘Schuman group’, to protest against the
>   acceptance of the OVP’s strategy among the EPP leadership and to reaffirm
>   their allegiance to what they thought should be the common ethos of the
>   EPP, namely traditional Christian democratic values and a strong
>   commitment to a federal Europe. (In the spring of 2004, some of the
>   founders of the Schuman group left the EPP-ED to create an autonomous
>   group with a few centre-left parties.)

Who exactly was in that "Schuman group" and what was the "autonomous
group" they ultimately created in 2004? (The paper doesn't get anymore specific than this in that regard.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain (by an elimination process) that the passage is talking about the 2004 formation of the [European Democratic Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Democratic_Party)
, given that it was also  led by a French politician and that

> It drew pro-European centrist parties from the European People's Party (EPP) group to form a new centrist multinational bloc. Its co-founder François Bayrou described it as a party for people being neither conservative nor socialist.

As a parliamentary group, it eventually merged into ALDE (now RE), but it is technically still a distinct European party.

I don't really know why the initial group was called "Schuman" though... I'm guessing it was a reference to [Robert Schuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Schuman) rather than any actual member of the group.

Comment: Schuman Is the name of a roundabout in the middle of the European quarter. It is where the hq of the commission is located. My guess is that they came up with the idea over some drinks near Schuman.